# unable to excute C code in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am currently working on a college-project in which the user enters a C code in a form and expects the output in the browser. I am working on this project in rails. 
here is the code for my form

```
<%= form_tag({action: :show}, {method: :get}) do %>

Comment: <%= text_area_tag(:comment, nil, :rows => 5, :cols => 15) %>
  <%= submit_tag ("Save data") %>
<% end %>
```

i have accessed the code from my controller from the following code and saved it to a file locally

```
@code_from_form = params['comment']

        path = "/home/User/test.c"
        content = @code_from_form
        File.open(path, "w+") do |f|
        f.write(content)
```

I have read in a forum to run a file use

```
system cc program.c
```

I included this in my controller but i get the following error "undefined method `cc'"

i have added the following gem to myGemFile

```
gem 'RubyInline'
```

and included the following code in my controller .

```
inline do |builder|
    builder.c_singleton '
    int testfunc() {
      return 0;
    }'
  end
  p testfunc
```

I get the following error

```
undefined method `inline' for #<ChallengesController
```

Should i use CGI scripts in C?

Comment: The argument to `system` needs to be a string, eg `system "cc program.c"`

Comment: `require 'inline'` in controller?

Comment: I changed my code to system "cc program.c" but i don't get the output

Comment: Thamks
i included require 'inline' in my controller
but that doesn't seem to work
i still get the same error "undefined method `inline' for #<ChallengesController"

Comment: I tried to store the output from system in a variable
like 
output = system "cc program.c"
p output
but i cant see any ouput

Answer (score 0):

The `system` method calls a system program that can be passed as a string. 
`system` returns `true` if the command gives zero exit status, `false` for non zero exit status. Returns `nil` if command execution fails. If the program you are trying to execute does not exist, `system` return `nil`.

When you write:

```
system "cc program.c"
```

You are executing the `cc` program on the input the file `program.c`. Here I suspect that `cc` is not installed on the computer running the Ruby script. On linux/unix `cc` stands for C Compiler and is usually installed with the Gnu C Compiler `gcc`. Try installing `gcc`.

Edit:
Since what you want is to show to the user the program's output you then have to execute the compiled program and collect it's output. By default `cc program.c` creates an executable named `a.out` in the current directory, to execute it and get its output do:

```
output = `./a.out`
```

If you surround a program with backticks it will be executed as if you run it with `system` and it will also return its output as a string.

Comment: Thanks
I am currently using gcc version 4.8.2 (Ubuntu 4.8.2-19ubuntu1)
On executing this command
output = system "cc test.c" 

output contains false

Comment: @pokiri read my answer: system returns `false` for non zero exit status. This means that `cc test.c` is returning a non zero exit status which means that compilation failed.

Comment: but this is the code which i have written in my program.c
#include<stdio.h> main() { printf("Hello World"); } 
how can this fail??

Comment: @pokiri Does the program have a newline after `#include<stdio.h>`?

Comment: actually NO eventhough i provide the input from textbox with newline
and when I printout the content of the textbox i get it as: "#include<stdio.h> main() { printf("Hello World"); }" 
Does the new line really matter??
provided i make some manipulations and get the new line inserted
I can only get the output as either 'true' or 'false' using 'system' 
How can i get 'Hello world ' as my output???

Comment: Yes it matters. I feel like we are moving to an unrelated topic. Consider voting/accepting the answer if you found it useful.

Comment: @pokiri I updated my answer to show how to run a program and read its stdout.

Comment: thanks @mziccard
when i typed my code in the text_area as defined above
it gets saved in the file in the same format as i have entered i.e., including all the new line characters 
now when I write the following code
output = system "cc #{path}"
where path =" /home/User/test.c"
I still get false when i print out the value of output

Comment: I get exitstatus as "1" @mziccard
but when i compile the same file using gcc in my terminal 
i get no error